# Batch File Deleting extra files

Tags: string, batch-file, delete-file, plc

Our programming archives contain tons of PLC programs (thousands of files)

Was recreating our backup structure, and wanted to filter through some of the junk. Made a batch file to delete all folders containing BAK with extension .acd, all files with .SEM, and .WRK, as these three are extra files that are created with opening the program, and are not needed. Some have gotten copied to the archives and duplicated many times.

I tested it on a copy of the folders, and wanted to run it routinely before the structure gets duplicated to other backup systems to prevent the backups from becoming cluttered again.

Here's the script I used:

`del /q /s "Y:\Bays\*BAK*.acd"`

`del /q /s "Y:\Bays\*.Sem*"`

`del /q /s "Y:\Bays\*.Wrk*"`

It deleted thousands of files, but as I watched I noticed three that did not make sense to me.

See the middle two deleted files:
[image: See the middle two deleted files]

"With Email" file:
[image: "With Email" file]

These three were deleted, yet don't contain *BAK* in their names. I don't want to routinely run this if it will risk removing any copies of programs that aren't the automatically generated ones. Just hoping someone may be able to explain why these three were the only ones out of the thousands of deleted files to not follow the rule.

Comment: Type `dir /S /X "Y:\Bays\*BAK*.acd" | findstr /I "BAK[^\\]*\.acd$"` and post the output; maybe the short 8.3 file names match a specified pattern…

Answer (score 0):

As you know, batch cannot delete files from directories with spaces between words. That's actually a bug that cannot be fixed, and wasn't built-in. So, I think that it's because of the unknown file extension, it happened the same to me. To make it known to your device, type regedit at the search bar, go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, add a new key, and name it as the extension. Close regedit and try again.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks. Useful information. However the files I'm wondering about was not why wasn't something deleted, but rather why was it deleted. As the three I'm talking about do not contain BAK in the names. Their extension was .ACD and the files themselves contained underscores in the name, not spaces.

Comment: I just created a directory, its name containing a space, created a file inside it, went back to the parent directory and deleted the file from there. So it is possible to delete files from directory names with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Volume has property to enable generate short file names (8.3).
This property affects the execution of commands (del, for).

I have volume D where 8dot3 name creation is disabled
There is a file with name 1.abcd in folder.
Command **for %i in (*.abc) do echo %i** not find any files

[image: 8dot3 name creation is disabled]

I have volume C where 8dot3 name creation is enabled
There is a file with the same name 1.abcd in folder.
Command **for %i in (*.abc) do echo %i** find this file

[image: 8dot3 name creation is enabled]

Maybe if you use long file names then you need to disable generating short file names. You can do it with [fsutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name).